# Collaborative Markdown Editor

Tags: markdown

- Write in markdown.
- Edit the documents locally (macOS) using an editor such as Atom, Sublime, IntelliJ.
- Team members can comment on lines.
- Good search and folder organisation.

I currently use Quip, but I prefer writing documents in Markdown using a local (macOS) text editor - such as Atom, Sublime, IntelliJ.

Comment: "local" means on what OS? How much are you willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions? How do you expect collaboration (multiple users edit the same file at the same time) to work with a local solution? How shall a Markdown document deal with comments, which are not in the format's specification?

Comment: @lzzy re: conflicts: Good question. Maybe when I save, it tries to get a lock on the file, if it fails - it asks me if I want to see conflicts (simple git conflict view).

Comment: re: comments: Tricky. Maybe insert an <div> with an id that links to the comment. Comments only viewable in the web interface.

Comment: Ah. I vaguely remember there was something with using HTML-comments for "special stuff" (i.e. wrapping it inside `<!-- {stuff-here} -->`), so it would not be processed with the "normal output". Yeah, that should be possible then. But merging might get nasty for the "technically challenged" when it comes to conflicts.

Comment: > nasty merging. Yeh. Maybe some kind of macOS menubar tool to lock files that are edited and notify, request lock, etc.

Comment: @vaughan What's wrong with combination of your favorite text editor with a markdown plugin and git? Gitlab and Bitbucket both offer more than enough space (especially for .md files) for private repositories.

Comment: @andselisk Yeh that could work. Perhaps a good markdown commenting solution is all that is needed. Or perhaps using a github issues page to discuss the contents. Like a code review, but linked to an html element in the markdown file, rather than a commit/line.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Madoko`?

- http://www.madoko.net

  - http://www.madoko.org/reference.html (or `*.pdf`)

You can connect to your local documents offline via the npm package `madoko`.

Also, there's a video introduction from Microsoft Research, do a search for it.